# How do I implement Request throttling in a Java EE environment?

Tags: jakarta-ee, request, jms, weblogic-10.x, throttling

One of our application accepts requests through a message queue and dials a telephony call for every request.

There are 2 telephony systems involved in dialing a call. One has a limitation on number of calls that can be initiated in a second but no limit on parallel calls and other system has a limitation of concurrent calls that can be active at any point in time.

The later requirement is handled in the Java EE layer by having a message queue with a predefined number of MDBs not exceeding the limit.

Can anyone please suggest how do I implement the first limitation (call initiation) in the Java EE layer (weblogic 10.3)?

Comment: 2 questions: 1. Is message sequencing important? 2. Do you want to support clustered environments (the MDB pool exists per JVM)?

Comment: Message sequencing is important to an extent (say process in any order before an expiry of 20 mins ). I do not need to support clustering.

Answer (score 1):

The only idea I come up with is to have a number of MDB's equal to the initiation limit, and have them sleep for 1 second after call initiation, and before getting the next message.

There might be a way to do it in the Queue provider, that isn't necessarily available via JMS.  You'd have to check the documentation.

Comment: Thanks. There are 2 constraints in the participating system, one on call initiation (For e.g 2 calls in a sec ) and the other on maximum parallel calls(100 calls any time)  , I have sized the MDBs equal to the maximum parallel calls since we need the maximum throughput reducing the number to call initiation will result in under utilization of the resources.

Comment: With my suggestion, you would have 2 MDB's for initiation.  Each would initiate a call, and sleep for 1 second.  Guaranteeing never having more then 2 in one second.

Comment: Let me put it this way, My application receives messages through a Queue , needs to dial a call for each msg received. The telephony system has no limit on the number of calls active at any time but has a limit on call initiations. for e.g i can only initiate 2 calls in a second but can have as many calls active once initiated. By limiting the MDBs to 2 I limit my system's capacity. I am looking for a solution safe to be used in a J2EE context. Please help (MDBs will be active through out the life time of the call which can range from 10 secs to 200 secs)

Comment: Ok, I was thinking use the MDB's for call initiation only, and they would delegate to a call handler.  The call handler would be around for the 10-200 seconds necessary, leaving the MDB's to just fire up the call handlers.  The call handlers themselves could be MDB's, EJB's or pojo's.